# Ratio of the sum of the four circles to the area of the original right triangle

Tags: geometry

A right triangle is divided into two smaller right triangles by the altitude $CD$ to its hypotenuse $AB$ as shown in the diagram. Circle $O$ with radius $r$ is inscribed in the $\unicode {0x25FA} BCD$. The $\unicode {0x25FA} CAD$ contains 3 circles which are tangent to each other and also to the sides of the triangle as depicted in the diagram. **All four circles are congruent**. What is the ratio of the sum of the areas of the four circles to the area of the original $\unicode {0x25FA} ABC$?

[image]

**My solution:**

Say, $BC = a, CA = b, AB = c$.

As $\unicode {0x25FA} BCD \sim \unicode {0x25FA} CAD$, it is easy to see that $\angle OBC = \angle ACE$ and $\angle OCB = \angle CAG$. Given that the circles are congruent,

$BH = CI, CH = AJ, IJ = 4r$.

So we get, $b-a = 4r$.

Given $\unicode {0x25FA} BCD \sim \unicode {0x25FA} ABC$, the ratio of their inradius will be the ratio of their hypotenuse (or other sides). So,

$r \times c = a \times \dfrac{a+b-c}{2}$ or $c(b-a) = 2a(a+b-c)$ or $(a+b)(2a-c) = 0$.

So, $c = 2a$ and hence $\angle A = 30^0, \angle B = 60^0$.

$BC = 2BD = 2r(1+cot30^0) = 2r(\sqrt3+1)$
$AC = BC+4r = 2r(3+\sqrt3)$

Area of $\unicode {0x25FA} ABC = \dfrac{1}{2} \times AC \times BC = 4r^2(2\sqrt3 + 3)$

So, the ratio of the sum of the areas of 4 circles to the triangle ABC

$= \dfrac{4 \pi r^2}{4r^2(2\sqrt3+3)} = \dfrac{\pi}{3} (2\sqrt3-3)$

**Coming to the purpose of posting the question here -**

1. With the arrangement of the congruent circles and division of the triangle $ABC$, we come to the conclusion that $c = 2a$. I am getting to it with some calculation. Is there a more obvious way to get to the conclusion or is there any theorem which establishes it?
2. Is there a better and faster solution to the problem than what I already have?

Comment: [This question has been posted here](https://brilliant.org/problems/4-circles-in-a-triangle/)

Comment: OK, I think it is a paid site and I cannot get in. So I do not know if it has a solution and if it is better or not.

Comment: @MathLover, you do not need to pay anything for viewing the solution to that problem. Payment on brilliant.org is for premium membership. You just need to login into the website.